Anime JS Timeline Issue
anime
  .timeline()
  .add({
    targets: ".ml5 .letters-left",
    opacity: [0, 1],
    translateX: ["-100%", 0],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 600,
    offset: "-=60",
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".ml5 .letters-right",
    opacity: [0, 1],
    translateX: ["100%", 0],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 600,
    offset: "-=60",
  });

I am facing issue due to which letters-left and letters-right are coming one after other (first left then right) they are not coming together & I want them to come together.
I've tried changing offset of both of them to different values but still the issue persists.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Offset shouldn't be a property of your parameters object, it's an argument handed directly to add():
myTimeline.add(parameters, offset);

So your code should be something more like:
anime
  .timeline()
  .add({
    targets: ".ml5 .letters-left",
    opacity: [0, 1],
    translateX: ["-100%", 0],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 600,
  }, "-=60")
  .add({
    targets: ".ml5 .letters-right",
    opacity: [0, 1],
    translateX: ["100%", 0],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 600,
  }, "-=60");

